# Row_Number Date Range

Tags: sql

I'm trying to fill in a table that has an PersonID with an appointment date, and whether or not a follow up call was made after the visit.

Tbl_Appt

```
    PersonID     Appt_Date
    1            1/1/2016
    1            1/3/2016
    1            1/9/2016
    1            1/31/2016
```

Tbl_Call

```
    PersonID     Call_Date
    1            1/5/2016
    1            2/1/2016
```

Desired Table: Tbl_FollowUp

```
    PersonID     Appt_Date   Follow_Up_Flag
    1            1/1/2016    N
    1            1/3/2016    Y
    1            1/9/2016    N
    1            1/31/2016   Y
```

The Tbl_FollowUp.Follow_Up_Flag is = Y when the Tbl_Call.Call_Date is > Tbl_Appt.Appt_Date and before the next appt.

I assume I would use Row_Number/Partition, but these functions allude me (see my prior posts).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: your desired output seems wrong. why is there a Y next to 1/3/2016?

Comment: Since this is not your first SQL question, you should by now that it's very important to always specify which database you are using. SQL Server? And if so, which version? It may determine which window functions are available.

Comment: @Kostya -- because 1/5 is between 1/3 and 1/9 comparing sequential records.

Comment: never mind my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not extremely trivial, but assuming you have access to `window functions` such as `row_number`, then here's an option using `lead` and an `outer join`:

```
select a.personid, a.appt_date,
    case when c.personid is null then 'N' else 'Y' 
    end as follow_up_flag
from (
      select personid, 
        appt_date, 
        lead(appt_date) over (partition by personid order by appt_date) next_appt_date
      from tbl_appt
) a left join tbl_call c on c.personid = a.personid and 
            c.call_date > a.appt_date and 
            (c.call_date < a.next_appt_date or a.next_appt_date is null)
order by a.appt_date
```

Comment: This is great! The only thing I had to change was the Follow_Up_Flag:  case when c.call_date is null then 'N' else 'Y' 
    end as follow_up_flag  :) :)